# What can happen if my database is public?

Tags: security, firebase-realtime-database

Do I need to worry about it? I made an android app for my personal usage and maybe for friends. 
My real-time database have user IDs and messaging tokens for the users. I want to learn possible risks if exists and what can a third person do with these information.

Also he/she can reach more details that are not in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that someone can very easily read and write the entire contents of your database.  If you're on the Spark plan, they could cause your app to stop working because the quota is exceeded.  If you're on the Blaze plan, you could end up paying for as much data as someone writes into it.

Whether or not you should worry about it is a matter of personal opinion, but you should be aware of the consequences.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't understand a point. Who are those people can access it? How can they get my data although I don't share with anyone? In short, can you define who is "someone" please?

Comment: Anyone on the internet who knows the name of your project.  They can simply using the REST API to read and write the data.